# what are the advantages of using maven to generate a WS client from a WSDL?

Tags: web-services, maven, jakarta-ee, wsdl

My WSDL contains 20 web services and I have to generate a WS client to invoke those web services.

I started with wsdl2java to generate the sub then I developed the JSP files and servlets and it seems to work, I am using Axis2 with Tomcat 7 on Eclipse, but many developers use Maven to do the work so I wonder what are the advantages of using Maven to create the client ?

I am a newbie so can you please explain to me this point in a level that I can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven itself won't do it for you, it may only be used to trigger *generate code* for you. So it does not matter whether you use ant or maven or gradle from command line or within eclipse - in the end you always call the same mechanism to generate the *portable artifacts* from the WSDL.

Comment: thank you  But if I want to create a web application client to invoke the web services, won't using Maven will be helpfull  ?

Comment: @Tanboula: Of course Maven can be helpful, but Maven is a build management tool - it has nothing to do with the fact that you need portable artifacts from your WSDL which your client is based on. One of the advantages of Maven is its principle of convention, so your project layout is the same as in every other project and it's easy to adapt examples you find or use archetypes to create the initial project.